# React Service Worker not reachable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am learning about PWAs and I am trying to apply my new knowledge about cache strategies on a React app, but despite I have changed the line at **src/index.js** to `serviceWorker.register()` and this works, the recently created file **public/service-worker.js** is not being reached.

Just to try I have created a "custom register function" on **src/serviceWorker.js**:

```js
export function customRegister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/service-worker.js')
    .then(reg => {
      reg.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installation = reg.installing;

        installation.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installation.state === 'activated') {
            console.log('%cActivated SW', 'font-size: 1.2rem; color: green; font-weight: bolder');
          }
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('%cError while registering SW:', 'font-size: 1.2rem; color: red; font-weight: bolder');
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Despite the service worker is registered, this is the result when I change on `src/index.js` to `serviceWorker.customRegister()`:

[image: SW activated]

But I just added these functions (one at time) and none of these works:

```js
self.oninstall = () => {
    console.log('SW install');
};
```

Or

```js
self.addEventListener('install', () => {
    console.log('SW install');
});
```

I have tried different codes but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is self refer to? and also I think it better to use react service worker because it wort by "Facebook" and I believe this script was tested many times

Comment: `self` is referred to `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`. It's good I guess, but as I already said I am "learning", so I think I need to use my "own" strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but even if I deleted the service-worker.js the **serviceWorker.js** registered the SW and no error was triggered.

The only way I found to properly register the SW was changing the SW name on **serviceWorker.js**:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sw.js`;
    ...
}
```

## Edit:

I guess this is the expected outcome since React service worker is made for Production as it says on [this Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2396).

This was the function I made on **src/sw-register.js**:

```js
export function LocalRegister() {
    const swPath = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/sw.js`;
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.onload = () => {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register(swPath)
                .then(registration => {
                    registration.onupdatefound = () => {
                        const installation = registration.installing;
                        installation.onstatechange = () => {
                            if (installation.state === 'activated') {
                                console.log('%cSW Activated', 'font-size: 1.2rem; color: green; font-weight: bolder');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('%cError while registering SW:', 'font-size: 1.2rem; color: red; font-weight: bolder');
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Then I just referred to this on **src/index.js**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
//import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import * as serviceWorker from './sw-register';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.LocalRegister();
```